# Java JPA. SQL accept '_' wrong with LIKE

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA Query to get search results from database. I`m searching results by name or description (these are columns in my table).

```
List<MyClass> findByNameIgnoreCaseContainingOrDescriptionIgnoreCaseContaining(String name, String description);
```

And here is the problem when user try to search something that contains special characters (for example "`Book ( _ , # , %, etc.)`"). In this case JPA build SQL Query using `LIKE` which accept underscore or other special character like a part of LIKE template instead of search criteria. How can I avoid this?

P.S. I`m using MySQL

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure how it works in spring-data and maybe there's a cleaner way, but you can shield those characters before passing them to the query.

For example:

```
String name = name.replace("_", "\\_");
String description = description.replace("_", "\\_");
```

and then call `findByNameIgnoreCaseContainingOrDescriptionIgnoreCaseContaining(name, description)`.

Comment: Probably same thing for '%' ?

Comment: @LukStorms Looks like it

Comment: The problem is not only in underscore, it's about all special characters. Result is still wrong when user types #, % and others. In your answer I`m protecting my query only from underscore, but I need protect it from any special characters. 

Let me try to explain it on example. User types in search input field on UI "Book" and get the results. If User types in search input field "Book_" or "Book%" or something else there must be empty results as there is no appropriate name or description in db.

Comment: @hlibOstapenko you can shield other special characters the same way, by adding double slashes before them. Still, maybe there's a cleaner way to solve your problem.

Comment: @htshame so the only way to avoid this is manually replace every problem special character? And no other possible variants?

Comment: @hlibOstapenko maybe there are, but I'm not aware of them. Same as you, I'd like to know a better way to do it.

Comment: If the string is used in a LIKE then it's probably only `_` and `%` that need to be escaped. [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html). But it would't be needed if [INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) is used.

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone) I`ll try find some other way, but at least I have one working variant :)